# VW font-size not displaying on normal state

Tags: css, sass, font-size, viewport-units

I came across this strange phenomena while toying on codepen.

I set my various font sizes as vw values, but it created some strange behavior:

The font size will only display correctly while my elements are on hovered state, and will render as 0px if they are not.

Here's my SCSS :

```
$title:2vw;
$subtitle:1.5vw;
$text:1vw;
```

and

```
p {
color:$red;
font-size:$text;
}

h1 {
color:$black;
font-size:$title;
}

h2 {
color: lighten($black, 20%);
font-size:$subtitle;
}
```

Those elements have no set class in my html, except being children of divs which are styled as such:

```
@mixin div {
   border:$border;
   border-radius:$border-radius;
   background-color:$green;
   color:$black;
   padding:$padding;
   margin:$margin;
   &:hover {
     background-color:$black;
     color:$green;
     h1 {
     color:$green;
   }
   p {
     color:$green;
   }
  }
 }
```

And here is the link to the pen page: http://codepen.io/rlacorne/pen/tgrbn

Anyone knows what's happening? It's bugging me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Leaving the question open, but it seems that re-setting the z-index of elements on window resize will force a calculation of the proper font-size. My pen has been edited with such practice.

Comment: In what browser do you observe this bug? I can't reproduce it in neither Firefox 32 nor Chrome 37 (both on Windows 7).